# Calculating attibute for a layer objects based on objects of another layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, line, expression

I have a point layer. The points have float attribute "cost".
I also have a line layer with a simple line between every two points from the point layer.

I want to calculate a new attribute for the line layer using a such formula:
new attribute for line layer = cost(from point1) + cost(from point2)

How can I make a geometry expression for it?
[image]

Comment: What is your desired output? What does your input look like, how many points it has? What should be done with the `"cost"`-attribute?

Comment: Cost is a field of a point layer. It's the distance from a point to the polygon boundary. I calculated it through Field calculator. Then I created a line between every pair of points and now I want to calculate line weight based on cost field. I have a lot of points, 2 thousands or more. And there are many more lines between them. In short I try to build a graph and calculate manhetton distance for its edges. May be I'm not doing it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QGIS expressions for this, where `point` is the name of the point layer:

```
array_sum(
    overlay_nearest (
        'point',"cost",limit:=2
    )
)
```

The expression used to label the line:

[image]

---

**Variant for more complex situations**

This is the standard case. If, however, you have more than two points on your line like in the following image, you get wrong results: see the middle line. It takes the two points at the left 3+8=11. To avoid that, you only want to sum up points that overlap the start- and endpoints of the line.

[image]

For this, the epression is a bit more complex:

[image]

```
array_sum(
    with_variable(
        'cv',
        'array_max(
            array_foreach (
                overlay_nearest (''point'',$id, limit:=-1),
                case 
                when 
                    within (
                        xx_point ($geometry),
                        buffer (
                            geometry ( 
                                get_feature_by_id (''point'', @element)
                            ),
                            0.01
                        )
                    )
                then 
                    attribute (
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            ''point'', 
                            @element
                        ), 
                        ''cost''
                    )
            end
            )
        )',
        array_foreach (
            array('start','end'),
            eval (replace (@cv, 'xx', @element))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I explained my problem incorrectly. The more correct question is How can I refer to the point layer attribute to calculate a new line layer attribute?

Comment: I calculated distance of an every point from the boundaries of the polygon(attribute "cost" by your method)  and now I want to сalculate weight of lines between two points to build a graph. And then I'm planning to use Dejkstra algorythm for such a graph